# Right click on project in Spring tools suite freeze the IDE

Tags: eclipse, spring-tool-suite

I'm using Spring tools suite as main IDE. But a feel days ago I discovered one bug. 
Right clicking on project in eclipse caused freeze on the IDE. If eclipse is working for about half an hour this big disappear.

My current version of Spring tools suite 3.8.3. I changed the work space and the IDE still freezing.

Any idea why this is happening ?

Best regards, 
Petar.

Comment: I would recommend to file an issue at https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-ide and attach a thread dump while STS freezes. That would help a lot to identify the underlying issue. The best way to do this is to reproduce the freeze, then, while STS freezes, use jps to find the process ID and then jstack <processID> to capture a full thread dump. Then attach that thread dump to the issue and we can take a detailed look. Also, in case you have them, a set of concrete steps how to reproduce this issue would be awesome, too. Thanks a lot for your help!!!

Answer (score 0):

In case if you closed the STS with debugger ON. First restart the STS, stop the debugger and  the try a right click. 
Worked for me.